# Trying to pick up a battery. "NullReferenceException" error

Tags: nullreferenceexception

Full error is "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
battery.OnTriggerStay (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/battery.cs:32)"

heres my screen in case its something i didnt do in the inspector: [http://imgur.com/a/wWSGJ](https://imgur.com/a/wWSGJ)

here is my code (not sure if you need my flashlight code too):

public class battery : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float a;
public float b;
public float c;
public float d;

public bool showText;
public int Bat;

public GameObject Flight;
public int mainBat;

public bool safeRemove;

void Start()
{
    showText = false;
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    showText = true;
    if (!safeRemove) 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.E)) 
        {
            mainBat = Flight.GetComponent<flashlight> ().batLevel;
            Bat = 20;
            Flight.GetComponent<flashlight> ().batLevel = Bat +- mainBat;
            safeRemove = true;

            if (safeRemove) 
            {
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    showText = false;
}
void OnGUI()
{
    if (showText) 
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width/ 2.66f, Screen.height/ 3.48f, Screen.width/ 3.78f, Screen.height/ 16.1f), "Press 'E' to pick up");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question and add the relevant language tag so we know what this question is about and people able to answer it are more likely to see it. And yes, it's generally preferred / necessary to include a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi @Mariah as Dukeling said quite appropriately, you will need to add the relevant language tag